# How to remove string quotations, commas and parenthesis from Python itertools output?

Tags: python, python-itertools, more-itertools

**This nice script** generates all 4 character permutations of the given set `s`, and prints them on new lines.

```py
import itertools


s = ('7', '8', '-')

l = itertools.product(s, repeat=4)

print(*l, sep='\n')
```

**Sample output:**

```
...
('9', '-', '7', '8')
('9', '-', '7', '9')
('9', '-', '8', '7')
('9', '-', '8', '8')
('9', '-', '8', '9')
...
```

I can't figure out how to remove all single quotes, commas and left/right parenthesis.

**Desired output:**

```
...
9-78
9-79
9-87
9-88
9-89
...
```

**Tried adding:**

```py
c = []

for i in l:
    i = i.replace(",", '')
    c.append(i)

print(*c, sep='\n')
```

**Error:** `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'replace'`

**Also tried:** I can't seem to find where to put the `print(' '.join())` logic.

Comment: `print(*l, sep='\n')` is printing tuple in each line, which automatically adds brackets and commas when printed. try extracting the tuple elements and use `join` to create a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you are printing a value, you can use:

```
for vals in l:
    print("".join([str(v) for v in vals]))
```

This just joins all the characters, noting that `.join` requires the values to be strings.

You can also use:

```
for vals in l:
    print(*vals)
```

... but that has a space between values.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. Easily translated your solution to write-out to file using: `with open('out.txt', 'w') as f: for i in l:f.write(''.join([str(v) for v in i]) + '\n')`.